# cv2: двойной клик на кнопке клавиатуры

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть некоторый код:

```
key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == ord("y"):
//some code...
```

Он срабатывает по нажатию на клавишу "Y". Как мне нужно преобразовать данный код, чтобы он срабатывал только при двойном нажатии на кнопку "Y"? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант - запоминать предидущую нажатую клавишу,
что то вроде:

```
prev_key=None # this variable should be static
# ...
key = cv2.waitKey(1)
prev_key=key
if key == ord("y") and prev_key==key:
    # some code...
```

Если стоит задача не просто по кол-ву нажатий, а еще и по интервалу времени между нажатиями (как у мыши), то можно сохранять время нажатия и клавишу, а сравнивать клавишу и вычислять и сравнивать интервал между нажатиями

Comment: да так и сделал уже, но все равно спасибо большое!)